# Can MapReduce can be used for filtering log files or something other than counting a single metric?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to understand if MapReduce might be a good tool for a specific problem I have. I need to search through hundreds of log files to find specific hits from a few specific IP addresses and record the time, the ip address, and the url path.

All the examples of MapReduce I've seen related to log analysis seem to be counting a single metric, such as hits per hour. It seems like an overly simplified example that always emits an IntWritable of 1.

In my case, I am not really counting anything - its more of a filter. How would the map reduce steps look to output the timestamp, ip address, and url path of the specific addresses I am searching for?

I also may want to do some analysis to count several different metrics instead of the single "hits per hour". In order to count several different metrics is that generally done with multiple jobs or can a single job count several metrics?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you problem is embarrassingly parallel. You just want to perform the same operation on different input data in parallel.

That is exactly what map does. It divides your input in a number of splits, then execute the same code on each split. Done. You don't care about the reduce step.

You can also use Hadoop-streaming to execute a binary or a shell script as a mapper. You most likely already have the command to filter the data. You just need to parallelize it.

Now is Hadoop the right tool for you ? It depends. Hadoop is a beast to master, deploy, administrate but it brings scalability & fault-tolerance because a very limited paradigm. Your use case can also be addressed with lot of other tools, I believe that the keys here are:

- do you need HDFS ?
- do you want to invest in Hadoop integration (data import / export etc.) and troubleshooting ?

> I also may want to do some analysis to count several different metrics instead of the single "hits per hour". In order to count several different metrics is that generally done with multiple jobs or can a single job count several metrics?

Sometimes it can, but I cannot answer without more details. Try to read some material about map/reduce design patterns.

Comment: My question is really specific to Map Reduce. I would be fine using Hadoop Streaming or Amazon EMR. I am not really worried about setting up and running a Hadoop cluster. This is a one time problem where I need to search through a ton of log data.

Comment: Then you can give it a try. If you already have a binary or a script to do the filtering, I would just use [Hadoop streaming](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming) since it is available on [EMR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UseCase_Streaming.html) and specify the script as the mapper.

Comment: I have to provide a reduce script though too I believe. Would it just be an empty script or what would it just echo the input to output?

Comment: You don't. It's optional as written in the documentation. I'm sure you will be able to find some samples too.